# How To Create/Configure Facebook App's Platform via API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've seen this a couple times now and can't figure it out. I sign up for a SaaS service that ties into Facebook API. It prompts me to first create the Facebook App and then supply the App ID/Secret. Afterwards, it then goes behind the scenes and automatically creates the Platform (e.g. Facebook Canvas) and fills in the fields.

Digging through the SDK, I don't see anything about this. Scouring the web has landed me empty handed.

Does anyone know how this is done?

Thanks :)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/application

Comment: Oh, so that's how. Cool - thanks again!